# addFieldToFilter() doesn't have any impact in collection

Tags: magento

I am trying to filter collection data with below code

```
$collection = $collection->addFieldToFilter(
    'xyz_column',
     array(
         array('eq' => $value)
     )
);
```

But it is now working.

Comment: what is the `$collection` holding here? we can't help you if don't have time to explain the problem clearly.

Comment: @Ankita: xyz_column is the attribute name or something else.
you said it is working now then what the problem you are facing ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addFieldToFilter(array(
array('attribute'=>'xyz_column','eq'=>$value),
));
```

Comment: The way OP did is correct.. he/she has just not provided info for what actually the collection holds.

Comment: @Mr_Green: Yes , As you can see i also asked some question in comment .but i just put my understandability for this question and i think this will help her.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use

```
$Collection->clean()
```

Just before where I was applying filter and now it's working fine for me.